# How to change language of input method as device language changes

Tags: android, android-resources, android-input-method

I have created a custom keyboard with English `xml` and Russian `xml-ru` layout files.

When the user changes the device locale from **English to Russian** or **Russian to English**, the layout should change to selected locale.

In my case, it changes only when device orientation changes.

Comment: while changing the locale in device it closes keyboard and user have to open it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your resources in `onConfigurationChanged`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```